# el siguiente codigo me tira error trabajando con xml vb

Tags: xml, vb

Les comento hay una variable que en ves de darme el valor real me lo da mostrando system.xml.xmlelemento cuando en realidad el valor esperado es un 00,

comparto el codigo

```
Dim record As XmlNodeList
            Dim Respuesta As New Respuesta()
            Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

            doc.LoadXml(sRespCons)
            record = doc.SelectNodes("RESPUESTA/Adicionales")

            Respuesta.ListaRecord = New List(Of Response)
            Respuesta.confirmacion = doc.SelectSingleNode("RESPUESTA/Confirmacion").ToString()
            'Respuesta.descripcion = doc.SelectSingleNode("Descripcion").ToString()
            Dim clsrecord As Response

            If Respuesta.confirmacion = "00" Then
                'Respuesta.descripcion = "<Descripcion>TRANSACCION EXITOSA</Descripcion>"
                For Each nd As Xml.XmlNode In record
                    clsrecord = New Response()
                    clsrecord.nombre = nd.Item("nombre").InnerText
                    clsrecord.direccion = nd.Item("direccion").InnerText
                    clsrecord.importe = nd.Item("importe").InnerText
                    clsrecord.mensaje = nd.Item("mensaje").InnerText
                    clsrecord.cuenta = nd.Item("cuenta").InnerText
                    clsrecord.factura = nd.Item("factura").InnerText
                    Respuesta.ListaRecord.Add(clsrecord)
                Next
            End If
```

si me posiciono sobe lo que trae respuesta hay 3 capos confirmacion descripcion y lista record y la confirmacion me da el valor que les acabo de menciona

ojala pudieran orientarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

pudiste resolver el problema?

Lo que te esta mostrando ahi es un elemento XML pero veo que el "Count" es igual a 0, entonces lo interpreto como que hasta ese momento no te ha cargado nada en esa lista y puede que sea por eso que te presenta el error.

Te puedo recomendar dos cosas con lo poco que se de tu ejercicio:

- 1: Ponle un "Try Catch" a tu código.
- 2: La lupa que está al lado    izquierdo de "System.Xml.XmlElement"
  (En tu imagen de captura)    usualmente ofrece más información, dale
  click ahi y ve que más te    muestra.

Por otro lado veo que lo que intentas hacer es un tipo de validación de "Transacción Exitosa", por lo tanto intenta hacer la validación para saber si se hizo la transacción de otra forma.

Por ejemplo, si almacenas esa información en una base de datos entonces intenta validar la información haciendo un **Select** para saber si hay algún dato nuevo y de esa manera saber que la transacción se realizó "correctamente".

Comment: deberías añadir como hacer esa transacción de la que hablas al final y no solo decir que la haga

Comment: No conozco los parámetros de su ejercicio por eso no puedo darle un ejemplo util, pero tienes razon, le dare una idea.